# Losing Reputation for not commenting, while not yet able to comment

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, answers, deleted-answers

In my early beginnings at Stack Overflow, I corrected a question answer by giving a new answer, because I was not yet able to comment.

The person who gave the (almost) correct answer was somehow mad at me for not commenting to his answer, I posted my own and got some upvotes.

Then a moderator deleted my answer and added it as a comment, because he also thought it should have been a comment. (Remember, I was not yet able to comment)

Did I lost that reputation now it is changed to a comment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: Depends on how old your answer was and how many upvotes it got when it was deleted. If it was less than 3, then yes, the rep goes away.

Comment: if that is what happened you didn't "lose reputation for commenting" - you temporarily gained some rep on a non-answer and the rep went away when the answer did, leaving you with the same rep as when you started

Comment: Fortunately this would not be a problem with very little future activity, as the reputation required to comment is quite low.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it is not really a problem, I was just wondering how this would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I lost that reputation now it is changed to a comment?

That depends on how you look at it - what you really intended to do was comment, which isn't a rep-awarding activity. Because you were still in the trust-building stage, you hadn't earned the right to comment yet, so you worked around it - almost everyone else did that too, by the way. The points you had were "borrowed", and have now been "returned", in a way.

No SO points awarded, but it does help build your real reputation with other users. I recognize the names of users who consistently post helpful comments in the tags I follow, and I'm sure I'm not alone in that. So you're getting Karma, if you will.

And now that you've joined Meta, you got a bonus +100 anyway, so life is good!

Comment: Yes, I got the bonus, I joined it earlier though.

Comment: Not to worry - it happens. For instance, this question is likely to be duplicated to [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), and eventually closed - and then any rep points for the question and answers will go the way of the Unicorn.